# Swift 3.0 String issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I have a custom picker view and it works great but theres one problem. You have the ability to click the button again and the picker view is dismissed. But when it dismisses the text in the unbutton becomes blank and does not stay the same ("Select" is a button that opens up the picker view and its text changes when you choose something from the picker view to reflect what you chose. What i want to happen is if you click the select button(not the picker view) again, then the text in the unbutton will not change and become blank.

```
var pickValue:AnyObject? {
        didSet{
            if let pickValue = pickValue{
                Select.setTitle("\(pickValue)", for: UIControlState())
            }else{
                Select.setTitle("Select", for: UIControlState())
            }
        }
    }

@IBAction func Show(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let pickercontrol  = LCTableViewPickerControl(
            frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view!.frame.size.height + 150, width: view.bounds.size.width - 50, height: 150),
            title: "Please pick an item",
            value: pickValue,
            items: ["minute", "hour", "day", "month", "year"],
            offset: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        pickercontrol?.tag = 1
        view.addSubview(pickercontrol!)
        pickercontrol?.show(in: view) { [weak self](sender, item) in
            guard let view = sender as? LCTableViewPickerControl else{
                return
            }
            view.dismiss()
            self?.pickValue = item as AnyObject?
        }


    }
```

[The image when the picker view is initialized and your able to pick a value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAQSd.png)

[Here is a picture of the problem. After you click the button again. The picker view dismisses and the text inside the button becomes blank. I want to change it so that if the view is dismissed and no value is chosen from the picker view then the text inside the button stays the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1xHG.png)

Comment: be sure to use the "code sample" format rather than "code snippet" in the future. code snippet is for styling short  one-liners of code or a function name. The code sample format (done by indenting four spaces or highlighting and clicking the tool in the formatting bar) is for long code and adds scroll bars etc and makes larger code portions more readable.

Comment: I did it. Do you think you can fix it

Comment: I don't know anything about swift unfortunately. The site is peer reviewed for quality and I was just helping your post look more appealing for others to help with. Hope somebody can find the answer though. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set which controlState you want.  `for UIControlState.normal`

Comment: You may also want to consider safely unwrapping your optionals rather than force unwrapping them.  If the LCTableViewPickerControl initializer returns an optional you can initialize it and then say:
`guard let picker = pickercontrol else { return }'
This will keep you from force unwrapping (and crashing if it's nil) when adding as a subview.

Comment: Where are you initially setting the button title?  If you're doing it in 'viewWillAppear' it'll fire off again after you dismiss the modal view, so if you're setting the title there it'll set to whatever the initial value is.  I'm not fully understanding what's going on with such a limited picture.

Comment: I'm not able to skype now.  Do you have your code on github or something?

Comment: my skype and github id name is jackpaster22. You can message me on skype or github

Comment: could you please help me

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to store the current text and when clicking the dismiss button set the pickers selected title to the previously stored string.

This will enable you to scroll through make any number of selections and upon dismissal revert to the original value.